# standard way to perform a clean shutdown with Boost.Asio

Tags: c++, signals, console-application, boost-asio

I'm writing a cross-platform server program in C++ using Boost.Asio.  Following the HTTP Server example on [this page,](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html) I'd like to handle a user termination request without using implementation-specific APIs.  I've initially attempted to use the standard C signal library, but have been unable to find a design pattern suitable for Asio.  The [Windows example's](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/server/win_main.cpp) design seems to resemble the signal library closest, but there's a race condition where the console ctrl handler could be called after the server object has been destroyed.  I'm trying to avoid undefined behavior as specified by the C++ standard.

Is there a standard (and correct) way to stop the server?

To illustrate problems with using the C signal library:

```
#include <csignal>
#include <functional>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using std::signal;
using boost::asio::io_service;

namespace
{
    std::function<void ()> sighandler;
}

extern "C"
{
    static void handle_signal(int);
}

void handle_signal(int)
{
    // error - undefined behavior
    sighandler();
}

int main()
{
    io_service s;
    sighandler = std::bind(&io_service::stop, &s);
    auto old_sigint = signal(SIGINT, &handle_signal);
    if (old_sigint == SIG_IGN)
        // race condition?  raise SIGINT before I can set ignore back
        signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);
    auto old_sigterm = signal(SIGTERM, &handle_signal);
    if (old_sigterm == SIG_IGN)
        // race condition?  raise SIGTERM before I can set ignore back
        signal(SIGTERM, SIG_IGN);
    s.run();
    // reset signals so I can clear reference to io_service
    if (old_sigterm != SIG_IGN)
        signal(SIGTERM, SIG_DFL);
    if (old_sigint != SIG_IGN)
        signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);
    // clear reference to io_service, but can I be sure that handle_signal
    // isn't being executed?
    sighandler = nullptr;
    // io_service is destroyed
}
```

Comment: @Timothy are you asking how to install a signal handler for a signal like SIGINT? Or, what to do in that signal handler to shutdown your HTTP server?

Comment: @Sam added a csignal design example

Comment: @Timothy you cannot safely invoke `io_service::stop` from within your signal handler, even if it is wrapped in a `boost::function`. Doing so results in undefined behavior. Look at [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639909/standard-way-to-perform-a-clean-shutdown-with-boost-asio/4639977#4639977) for a list of functions you can call from within a signal handler.

Comment: @Timothy I retagged your question as `c++0x` since it looks like you are using the `auto` keyword.

Comment: @Sam added comment to show that UB, thanks

Comment: @Timothy undefined behavior means don't do what your doing. Even if it appears to work, it will randomly behave differently. You should use sigwait or only invoke async-signal-safe functions from within your signal handler.

Comment: Although my example is C++0x code, the question doesn't really ask about C++0x.  Perhaps the `c` tag would be better, since `csignal` is defined in the C standard.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Version 1.5.3 of Boost.Asio (to be integrated in upcoming boost 1.47 release?) has the `signal_set` class:

```
#include <boost/asio/signal_set.hpp>

// Register signal handlers so that the daemon may be shut down. You may
// also want to register for other signals, such as SIGHUP to trigger a
// re-read of a configuration file.
boost::asio::signal_set signals(io_service, SIGINT, SIGTERM);
signals.async_wait(
    boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::stop, &io_service));
```

**EDIT**

Now [included](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/signal_set.html) in Boost version 1.47

Comment: Interesting; Asio uses static variables to access data from a signal handler.  Is that not UB?

Comment: By just stopping io_service and leaving work undone, your application is subjected to random segfaults once the destructor of io_service is called.

Answer (score 5):

The [posix example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/server/posix_main.cpp) HTTP server is a good way to cleanly shutdown. One thread invokes `io_service::run` while another waits for a signal with `sigwait`.

Alternatively, you can install a signal handler but that it slightly trickier. There's a [very small list](http://linux.die.net/man/2/signal) of async-signal-safe functions you can invoke from within a signal handler.

> The routine handler must be very
>   careful, since processing elsewhere
>   was interrupted at some arbitrary
>   point. POSIX has the concept of "safe
>   function". If a signal interrupts an
>   unsafe function, and handler calls an
>   unsafe function, then the behavior is
>   undefined. Safe functions are listed
>   explicitly in the various standards.
>
> The POSIX.1-2003 list is
>
> _Exit() _exit() abort() accept() access() aio_error() aio_return()
>   aio_suspend() alarm() bind()
>   cfgetispeed() cfgetospeed()
>   cfsetispeed() cfsetospeed() chdir()
>   chmod() chown() clock_gettime()
>   close() connect() creat() dup() dup2()
>   execle() execve() fchmod() fchown()
>   fcntl() fdatasync() fork() fpathconf()
>   fstat() fsync() ftruncate() getegid()
>   geteuid() getgid() getgroups()
>   getpeername() getpgrp() getpid()
>   getppid() getsockname() getsockopt()
>   getuid() kill() link() listen()
>   lseek() lstat() mkdir() mkfifo()
>   open() pathconf() pause() pipe()
>   poll() posix_trace_event() pselect()
>   raise() read() readlink() recv()
>   recvfrom() recvmsg() rename() rmdir()
>   select() sem_post() send() sendmsg()
>   sendto() setgid() setpgid() setsid()
>   setsockopt() setuid() shutdown()
>   sigaction() sigaddset() sigdelset()
>   sigemptyset() sigfillset()
>   sigismember() signal() sigpause()
>   sigpending() sigprocmask() sigqueue()
>   sigset() sigsuspend() sleep() socket()
>   socketpair() stat() symlink()
>   sysconf() tcdrain() tcflow() tcflush()
>   tcgetattr() tcgetpgrp() tcsendbreak()
>   tcsetattr() tcsetpgrp() time()
>   timer_getoverrun() timer_gettime()
>   timer_settime() times() umask()
>   uname() unlink() utime() wait()
>   waitpid() write().

Comment: I've found a list of functions on [this page.](http://linux.die.net/man/2/signal)  However, it is POSIX-specific.  Does the C standard say anything different about this stuff?

Comment: @Timothy that is the correct link, I've edited my answer. I'm not overly familiar with the C standard, though I've never had trouble using only the functions listed in the signal man page from within a signal handler.